# how to migrate from opensaml 2.6 to 3.1.1

Tags: java, migration, opensaml

I have to migrate a class from opensaml 2.6 to opensaml 3.1.1
Compiling I obtain some errors

1)

```
Element plaintextElement = getElementAssertion(inputBean);
String xml = XMLHelper.prettyPrintXML(plaintextElement);
```

I can't find the class XMLHelper in the new version.

2)

```
DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
builderFactory = Configuration.getBuilderFactory();
Configuration.getMarshallerFactory().getMarshaller(assertion).marshall(assertion);
```

I can'f find class DefaultBootstrap and I can't find a class Configuration with the methods getBuilderFactory(), getMarshallerFactory()

3)

```
BasicCredential credential = new BasicCredential();
```

Now the contructor new BasicCredential() is not visible.

I haven't found documentation with deprecation indication.
What must I do to port this class to the opensaml 3.1.1 version?

Answer (score 31):

Not sure if you managed to upgrade to opensaml 3 already but since I came across this while attempting the upgrade myself I thought I'm gonna document what I found.

There's very little documentation as apparently it's not a priority for them at the moment (also mentioned here: [OpenSaml3 Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114290/opensaml3-documentation)), the most useful (even if by far not complete) page I found is this one: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Initialization+and+Configuration

1) There's a class `SerializeSupport` with a method `prettyPrintXML` in lib `net.shibboleth.utilities:java-support`

2) Initialization is now done via `InitializationService`
 e.g.

```
InitializationService.initialize();
```

You can retrieve the builder/marshallers via `XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport` e.g.:

```
XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getMarshallerFactory()
XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getBuilderFactory()
XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getUnmarshallerFactory()
```

Mind that opensaml is using the Java Service Provider API. In my case (using OSGi bundle `org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml`)  for parsing a SAML assertion I added the SPI config `META-INF/services/org.opensaml.core.config.Initializer` containing the following entries:

```
org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLObjectProviderInitializer
org.opensaml.core.xml.config.GlobalParserPoolInitializer
org.opensaml.saml.config.XMLObjectProviderInitializer
org.opensaml.saml.config.SAMLConfigurationInitializer
org.opensaml.xmlsec.config.XMLObjectProviderInitializer
```

**EDIT:** The above worked in a test but did not run in the OSGi container. Workaround for OSGi: [OpenSAML3 resource not found 'default-config.xml' in OSGi container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948303/opensaml3-resource-not-found-default-config-xml-in-osgi-container/39004323#39004323)

If you use the standard libraries (`org.opensaml:opensaml-core`, `org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api`, `org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl`, ...) you may not need to add any SPI config as the jars already contain SPI configs with a standard configuration for initialization.

3) There's a class `BasicCredential` in lib `org.opensaml:opensaml-security-api`. I don' see an alternative to providing a key during initalization.

Comment: So what could be the reason when i still get null instead of the (un) marshaller from the factory? `XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getMarshallerFactory().getMarshaller(authnRequest.getElementQName())`

Comment: Have you `InitializationService.initialize();`?

Comment: There's some helpful sample code at https://git.shibboleth.net/view/?p=java-opensaml.git;a=blob;f=opensaml-saml-impl/src/test/java/org/opensaml/saml/saml2/metadata/MetadataTest.java;hb=HEAD. Note that some of the initialization is in the superclass at `org.opensaml.core.xml.XMLObjectBaseTestCase#initXMLObjectSupport` which in turn inherits from `OpenSAMLInitBaseTestCase` (does nothing but `InitializationService.initialize()`).

Comment: I'm struggling with something similar to section 1) , for classes `SOAPHelper` and `WSSecurityHelper`. Anybody knows where those went ?

Comment: Probably `org.opensaml.soap.util.SOAPSupport` and `org.opensaml.soap.wssecurity.util.WSSecuritySupport`
https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/sites/site/java-opensaml/3.2.0/apidocs/org/opensaml/soap/util/SOAPSupport.html
https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/sites/site/java-opensaml/3.2.0/apidocs/org/opensaml/soap/wssecurity/util/WSSecuritySupport.html

Answer (score 0):

I am learning how to use the OS3 for development. This is one example to convert base 64 saml request to SAMLObject in V3 version. Hope it can help you.

The project see [the github repository](https://github.com/xmeng1/opensamlv3demo)

```
public class SAMLToolkit {

    public static SAMLObject convertBase64ToSaml(String base64Str) {
        byte[] decodedBytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            decodedBytes = Base64.decode(base64Str);
        } catch (Base64DecodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);
        //is = new InflaterInputStream(is, new Inflater(true));
        try {

            InitializationService.initialize();
            Document messageDoc;
            BasicParserPool basicParserPool = new BasicParserPool();
            basicParserPool.initialize();
            messageDoc = basicParserPool.parse(is);
            Element messageElem = messageDoc.getDocumentElement();
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getUnmarshallerFactory().getUnmarshaller(messageElem);

            assert unmarshaller != null;
            return(SAMLObject) unmarshaller.unmarshall(messageElem);
        } catch (InitializationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (XMLParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (UnmarshallingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (ComponentInitializationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for me unless I also add ´/META-INF/services/org.opensaml.core.config.Initializer´ which contains the config shown by @Clauds.

Comment: Using InitializationService.initialize() hangs indefintely