# OpenSaml3 Documentation

Tags: java, spring-security, saml, spring-saml, opensaml

Does anyone know if there is any documentation for OpenSaml3 anywhere?  Paid or otherwise?  I know there used to be a $15 book available, but I believe that only covers OpenSaml2.

I know this will probably get voted down as it not a programming specific question, but Spring-Saml lists SO as it's primary forum now (http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/).  SAML is a pain to implement without a good library and I think that Spring-SAML is the best thing available to someone writing on the JVM.  Since Spring-Saml looks to be abandoned and with OpenSaml2 coming to end-of-life soon. I would like to see if I can update Spring Saml to use the newer supported version of OpenSAML, but there seems to be no documentation (no migration guide, or even published javadoc) other than the src code.  Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT
I have just released a new edition of my book, A Guide to OpenSAML, covering OpenSAML V3. It should serve well as documentation. [Have a look here](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html)

[According to Brent Putman](http://marc.info/?l=shibboleth-dev&m=145833549418429&w=2) on the project the documenting tasks are not prioritized and documentation is therefore lacking. What is of documentation is, as I understand [this page](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Home)

Accordning to Brent there isn't a lot of visible change in the library from v2 to v3. So [my book](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv2.html), that you mentioned, should still work =)

There are some changes in initialization and messaging API as he mentions in the email.

There seems to have been some changes in the module structure so the javadocs are now more separate than before. Here is the javadoc for the [core](https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/opensaml/opensaml-core/3.1.1/opensaml-core-3.1.1-javadoc.jar/!/index.html) and [messaging API](https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/opensaml/opensaml-messaging-api/3.1.1/opensaml-messaging-api-3.1.1-javadoc.jar/!/index.html) modules.

Hopefully some more documentation will come along soon.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I'll give it a look.  I have purchased you book previously,  do you have any plans to add information on the bits that changed in v3?  Thanks!

Comment: I have plans on making a new edition with opensaml 3 and some other new parts like SLO. However I have no ETA