# How to "pretty print" or "dump" an opensaml assertion object using Java?

Tags: java, saml, opensaml

I am working with OpenSAML (2.6.6) and I was wondering if there is way (e.g., some utility method or something like that) to dump out or pretty print the contents of an OpenSAML Assertion object using Java?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 2):

I found this:

[how to migrate from opensaml 2.6 to 3.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793362/how-to-migrate-from-opensaml-2-6-to-3-1-1)

and that hinted that the OpenSAML XMLHelper class has a prettyPrintXML() method and I tried that and it works!

Jim